# HTML5 Canvas: position of drawing cursor

Tags: html, canvas, cursor, drawing, position

I can't find out how to get actual drawing cursor position after moveTo(). Check out my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10, 20);
// here i want to get from "ctx" actual offset
ctx.lineTo(20,30);
ctx.closePath();
```

Is there any way or I have to store offset in my own variables offsetX, offsetY ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean you have a bunch of relative path commands and you want to move them.

For instance, to draw a triangle at the top-left you would write:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100,0);
ctx.lineTo(50,100);
ctx.closePath(); // makes the last line for you
ctx.stroke();
```

So what if you want to use the same path but draw the triangle starting at (175, 175) instead? Instead of changing your `moveTo` and all subsequent drawing command, all you have to do is *translate* the context.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(175, 175);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100,0);
ctx.lineTo(50,100);
ctx.closePath(); // makes the last line for you
ctx.stroke();

// save/restore lets you undo the translation so the next object starts at (0,0)
// you could just call ctx.translate(-175, -175); at the end instead though
ctx.restore();
```

Translating the context changes the origin of the drawing surface, and allows you to move all of your coordinates (temporarily or not) with it. This means you can define a bunch of paths and redraw them using the same commands all over the place using `ctx.translate`.

See both triangles here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qzYFC/